# How can I spread a wallpaper out to 2 displays?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I have an early 2011 MBP powering 2 Thunderbolt displays. I have downloaded the proper resolution wallpapers from Digitalblasphemy's site (5120x1440), but can't figure out the setting to spread the wallpaper across both displays.

How do I spread the wallpaper across both displays?

Answer (score 4):

Natively in Mac OS X, you cannot spread a wallpaper over two displays in this fashion. You'll need to use Photoshop or your preferred photo manipulator to split the image in half and apply the wallpaper to the individual displays in System Preferences.

Comment: Really? Ok, does iPhoto have that functionality? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It does not, but previous does. iPhoto is for managing photos, not making graphics.

Comment: Thank you. That said, any program other than an expensive Photshop program have the power to do what I need, and that doesn't require a ton of effort and time to do so?

Comment: Well, in iPhoto, you can duplicate the photo and crop them both separately. There are even marquee tool preset sizes for common display sizes.

Comment: You can crop images in the Preview application. The cropping tool is found under Tools>Crop.